# Get line number using grep

Tags: tcl

I would like to get the line  number using `grep` command, but I am getting the error message when search pattern is not a single word:

```
couldn't read file "Pattern": no such file or directory
```

How should be the proper usage of the grep? The code is here:

```
set status [catch {eval exec grep -n '$textToGrep' $fileName} lineNumber]
if { $status != 0 }  {
    #error
} else {
    puts "lineNumber = $lineNumber"
}
```

Also if the search pattern is not matched at all, the returned value is : `"child process exited abnormally"`

Here is the simple test case:

```
 set textToGrep  "<BBB name=\"BBBRM\""
```

file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE AAA>
<AAA>
  <BBB name="BBBRM" />
</AAA>
```

Comment: Can you give the contents of variables `textToGrep`, `fileName`? Also the contents of the file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Pattern matching does not work.
- grep exits with error `child process
  exited abnormally` when pattern is not found

The first problem is because you are not enclosing the `textToGrep` within `double quotes`(instead of single quotes). So your code should be:

```
[catch {exec grep -n "$textToGrep" $fileName} lineNumber]
```

Second problem is because of the exit status of `grep` command. `grep` exits with error when the pattern is not found. Here is the try on a shell:

```
# cat file
pattern
pattern with multiple spaces
# grep pattern file
pattern
pattern with multiple spaces
# echo $?
0
# grep nopattern file
# echo $?
1
```

EDIT:

In your case you have special characters such as `<` and `>` (which have special meaning on a shell).

```
set textToGrep  "<BBB name=\"BBBRM\""
regsub -all -- {<} "$textToGrep" "\\\<" textToGrep
regsub -all -- {>} "$textToGrep" "\\\>" textToGrep
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am still get the same error: couldn't read file "<BBB name="BBBRM"": no such file or directory

Comment: That is because `<` and `>` carry special meaning on a shell. I have edited my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I also get problems with your code and a single word pattern!

First of all, I don't think you need the `eval` command, because `catch` itself does an evaluation of its first argument.

Then, the problem is that you put the `$textToGrep` variable in `exec` inside single quotes `'`, which have no meaning to Tcl.

Therefore, if the content of `textToGrep` is `foo`, you are asking `grep` to search for the string `'foo'`. If that string, including the single quotes, is not found in the file, you get the error.

Try to rewrite your first line with

```
set status [catch {exec grep -n $textToGrep $fileName} lineNumber]
```

and see if it works. Also, read the `exec` man page, which explains well these problems.

Comment: Are you sure the file contains what you are searching for? Looking at the `exec` man page, you have an example of checking that, using either `try...except` or `catch`. When the pattern isn't found in the file, `grep` exits with a non-zero result, and your script shows the error.

Comment: Sure, the pattern which I am searching for is in the file. I am getting the error like this:
couldn't read file "pattern which should be search": no such file or directory

Comment: That's the advice I'd give; whatever the problem is, it answers the _question itself._

Answer (score 2):

If your system has tcllib install, you can use the `fileutil::grep` command from the `fileutil` package:

```
package require fileutil

set fileName data.xml
set textToGrep {<BBB +name="BBBRM"}; # Update: Add + for multi-space match
set grepResult [::fileutil::grep $textToGrep $fileName]
foreach result $grepResult {
    # Example result:
    # data.xml:4:  <BBB name="BBBRM" />
    set lineNumber [lindex [split $result ":"] 1]
    puts $lineNumber

    # Update: Get the line, squeeze the spaces before name=
    set line [lindex [split $result ":"] 2]
    regsub { +name=} $line " name=" line
    puts $line
}
```

## Discussion

- When assigning value to `textToGrep`, I used the curly braces, thus allowing double quote inside without having to escape them.
- the result of the `::fileutil::grep` command is a lits of strings. Each string contains the file name, line number, and the line itself; separated by colon.
- One way to extract the line number is to first split the string (result) into pieces, using the colon as a separator. Next, I use `lindex` to grab the second item (index=1, since list is zero-base).
- I have updated the code to account for case where there are multiple spaces before **name=**

Comment: Is there some ways to trim the white spaces, before the grep from the xml(although this not related to this question)?

Comment: Did you mean trimming the white space off `  <BBB name="BBBRM" />` so it becomes `<BBB name="BBBRM" />`?

Comment: I mean trim the whitespaces before attributes:

so <BBB 2 whitespace name="BBBRM"  become:
<BBB one whitespace name="BBBRM"

Comment: I agree with Hai Vu. I think this will make your code portable to systems where `grep` command isn't even there.

Answer (score 1):

```
set textToGrep {\<BBB name="BBBRM"}
catch {exec grep -n $textToGrep $fileName} status 
if {![regexp "child process" $status]} {
puts $status
} else {
puts "no word found" 
}
```

I think you should do regular expression with child process. Just check above code if it works. In if statement you can process the status command as you like.

With the given example (in your post) the above code works only you need to use backslash for the "<" in the textToGrep  variable